# Stop jquery function from running once condition is met

Tags: jquery, function

My summarised script below runs a function perfectly. But the issue I'm stuck with is that I want to stop the function once the counter has reached 5. If I do console.log, I see it is still running.

How can I really stop it? Tried event.finish() and return false but did not work or I did it incorrectly. Can someone help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 98) {
        (... myfunction including a counter)
    if (counter == 5) {
           END FUNCTION
}
};
});
});
```

Comment: `return` will end the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always unbind the keypress event with [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
if (counter == 5) {
    $(document).off('keypress');
}
```